# /run out of space due to systemd

Tags: partitioning, systemd

I'm running 14.10 server edition, and I'm finding that my /run parititon is out of space. The paritioning scheme is the default one from the installer, with encrypted home and using LVM. This was originally a 13.10 server VM, ugpraded to 14.04 and then to 14.10.

Our network monitoring system periodically logs into this box with SSH (a few times every minute). I believe this is causing the partition to run out of space. df -h looks like this:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   33G   12G   20G  39% /
none                         4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         1.1G  4.1k  1.1G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        210M  210M     0 100% /run
none                         5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
none                         1.1G  181k  1.1G   1% /run/shm
none                         105M     0  105M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    247M   85M  150M  37% /boot
/home/X/.Private    33G   12G   20G  39% /home/X
```

I found that the /run/systemd/sessions directory has over 50000 files in it, which look like they're created every time something logs in. I'd like to know:

- Can I delete these files?
- Why does /run only have 200 MB of space available to it? Should I increase it?
- How do I stop all these files from being created?

Answer (score 0):

**systemd** is a system and session manager for Linux, compatible with SysV and LSB init scripts. systemd provides aggressive parallelization capabilities, uses socket and D-Bus activation for starting services, offers on-demand starting of daemons, keeps track of processes using Linux cgroups, supports snapshotting and restoring of the system state, maintains mount and automount points and implements an elaborate transactional dependency-based service control logic.

It is a **alternate boot manager** which **manages user session** and we suspect the files under **/run/systemd/session** probably could be session file. You can leave the latest session file and delete the rest.

Since it is only 200MB, you can take a copy of the files to some other directory and you can use the same if something goes wrong

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this fully answers my question. When I read through the session file, I see that the STATE field says closing. I'm guessing that the login session isn't fully closed, but what does this mean and how do I view the session state?

Comment: ` and we suspect the files under` - that is really terrible. Either it is, or it isn't. `systemd is a cancer for Linux` FTFY